# NFS Mount at boot isn't working

Tags: debian, mount, nfs

i have exported my /home directory and want to mount it on another VM. They are both in the same network and mount -a is working well but after I do a reboot I have to mount it manually again.

So i know that the network is not up when it's trying to mount at boot that's why I have put in "_netdev" but unfortunately it show's no effect.

This is my /etc/fstab:

```
X.X.X.X:/home /home  nfs  defaults,auto,_netdev 0 0
```

I have also tried:

```
X.X.X.X:/home /home  nfs  auto,nofail,noatime,nolock,intr,tcp,actimeo=1800,_netdev 0 0
```

And none of them works.

I really have to set it in fstab I am not allowed to use automount or either creating a script or anything else.

I am using Debian 9 on VirtualBox.

Answer (score 1):

Update: I found a solution. It seems like the fstab ignores my line because I want to mount /home but it says there is already /home mounted the local one. So I commented it out and now its there after boot :)

just commented it out:

```
#UUID=.... /home ext4 defaults 0 2
```